# Función en Javascript arroja undefined al querer imprimir el resultado a través de un alert

Tags: javascript, funciones, function, undefined, switch

En este algoritmo se simula calcular el precio de entradas para un cine en función de la cantidad y de las cuotas. El valor de la entrada por defecto es de 300 pesos. Hay una opción de pagar en 3 cuotas con tasa 20% y quedaría en $360 pesos. Hay otra opción de pagar en 6 cuotas con tasa 40% y quedaría en $420 pesos. El problema es que al final el último alert arroja undefined pero no entiendo el por qué ocurre esto.

```js
const precioEntrada = 300;

const cantidadEntradas = function () {
    return parseInt(prompt('Cada entrada cuesta $300, ¿cuantas desea adquirir?: '));
}

function simuladorPago(cantidad){
    let total = cantidad*precioEntrada;
    let total3cuotas = total + total*0.2;
    let total6cuotas = total + total*0.4;
    alert("Le queda un total de $" + total)
    alert("Puede abonar en 1 o 2 cuotas sin interes, \n 3 cuotas con una tasa de 20%, quedaría en $" + total3cuotas +" \n o 6 cuotas con una tasa del 40%, quedaría en $" + total6cuotas)
    let cuotas = parseInt(prompt("¿Qué elige?"));
    switch (cuotas){
        case 1:
            return alert("Abona $" + total);
        case 2:
            return alert("Abona en 2 cuotas sin interés de $" + total/2);
        case 3:
            total = (total + (total*0.2))
            return alert("Le queda un total de $" + total + " y abona en 3 cuotas de $" + total/3);
        case 6:
            total = (total + (total*0.4));
            return alert("Le queda un total de $" + total + " y abona en 6 cuotas  $" + total/6);
    }
}

alert(simuladorPago(cantidadEntradas()));
```

Comment: `alert` no devuelve nada, por eso cuando retornas uno obtienes `undefined`. También puedes usar `break` con el `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo tu código modificado:

-Quite tu **return** en los *case*

-Quite tu alert en la función final

```js
const precioEntrada = 300;

const cantidadEntradas = function () {
    return parseInt(prompt('Cada entrada cuesta $300, ¿cuantas desea adquirir?: '));
}

function simuladorPago(cantidad){
    let total = cantidad*precioEntrada;
    let total3cuotas = total + total*0.2;
    let total6cuotas = total + total*0.4;
    alert("Le queda un total de $" + total)
    alert("Puede abonar en 1 o 2 cuotas sin interes, \n 3 cuotas con una tasa de 20%, quedaría en $" + total3cuotas +" \n o 6 cuotas con una tasa del 40%, quedaría en $" + total6cuotas)
    let cuotas = parseInt(prompt("¿Qué elige?"));
    switch (cuotas){
        case 1:
            alert("Abona $" + total);
            break;
        case 2:
            alert("Abona en 2 cuotas sin interés de $" + total/2);
            break;
        case 3:
            total = (total + (total*0.2))
            alert("Le queda un total de $" + total + " y abona en 3 cuotas de $" + total/3);
            break;
        case 6:
            total = (total + (total*0.4));
            alert("Le queda un total de $" + total + " y abona en 6 cuotas  $" + total/6);
            break;

    }
}

simuladorPago(cantidadEntradas());
```